# What is the difference between a deep learning library that is built for research and for production?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, theano

I always see things like "a library for research but not so much for production"
What does that mean?
What should i choose?
Can i built a an advanced model (ex: to compete in image-net) using anyone of them?

Comment: It probably means that it's in an early stage of development (so there may be a lot of bugs, or there are important missing features, or the interface is unstable), or simply that it's slow. If in doubt, ask the maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

In general, code that is written for a production environment is going to be more robust. If you are a researcher and an unexpected null slips into your sample data, you might just fix it an re-run it. In production, this might blow up automated processes, cause live environments to go down, and other sorts of other catastrophes.

good production code is (at least to some degree) optimized for speed, makes no assumptions about any inputs it gets, fails gracefully and provides all sorts of data about how it is running for operations monitoring.

The trade off is that production can can be a bit more complicated to work with.